# Embeds not loading when sending message

Tags: javascript, discord

I am trying to make a script that repeatedly pings someone. When trying to put an embed, they don't register.

Code:

```js
const superagent = require("superagent");
const { log } = require('console');

// setInterval(() => {
    superagent.post("https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/person's user id/messages")
        .send({
            "content": "Asparagus",
            "flags": 0,
            "tts": false,
            "embeds": [
                {
                    "title": "Dontavious, spargus",
                    "type": "rich",
                    "description": "Spongebob, Asparagus Spongebob\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/the-one-with-raspberry/random-file-bucket/main/spargus.jpeg\nhttps://media.tenor.com/images/3b0e2a9e7fe3f5d70de933b4057c3b0e/tenor.gif",
                    "color": 16711680,
                    "author": {
                        "name": "Dontavious",
                        "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/the-one-with-raspberry/random-file-bucket/main/donta.jpg",
                        "icon_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/the-one-with-raspberry/random-file-bucket/main/donta.jpg"
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
        .set('Authorization', "don't steal my token!!")
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .end((err, res) => { if (err) throw err; log(`${res.body.embeds}`) })
// }, 2500)
```

`res.body.embeds` is returning nothing.

[image: running the pinger script, and getting nothing from the response's embeds field]

Checking Discord, there is nothing there either.

[image: me saying asparagus, as result of the api call]

How could I fix this?

Comment: After a quick test, I cannot reproduce the issue on my end. Are you sure the application is allowed to send embeds in that channel?

Comment: @LarryTLlama it's a DM channel, i have no idea